Check if any value from Array1 Contains any value from Array2
How can I check if a value from an Array Contains any value from an other Array ?
For example:
string[] array1 = {"1726KB12","271","MB192"}
string[] array2 = {"KB","L1","C9"}

Those are the two arrays i'm using. I need to check if any value from array2 is contained in array1 (in this case, "KB" from array2 is contained in array1 but is not identical).
Is there a way to catch this?
Every other solutions that i could find only check if both values are identical.

.NET 9 is still in preview as I am writing this, but an improvement to SearchValues will allow you to speed up this scenario: SearchValues object become better with .NET 9.

You can use LINQ's .Any() function to return a boolean value indicating that array1 contains any value that is present in array2:
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] array1 = {"1726KB12", "271", "MB192"};
        string[] array2 = {"KB", "L1", "C9"};

        bool containsValue = array1.Any(a1 => array2.Any(a2 => a1.Contains(a2)));

        if (containsValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("At least one value from array2 is contained within array1.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No value from array2 is contained within array1.");
        }
    }
}

